# Python thread doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, multithreading

well,I wrote a little snappet trying to know how to use python threading .
But strangely the following code just quit quickly without the expected output.
Is it because I shouldn't spawn threads by overiding the run() method?

```
import threading
from time import sleep
class mythread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,target=None,thread_num=5):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self,target=None)
        self.thn = thread_num

    def run(self):
        for i in range(self.thn):
            t = threading.Thread(target=self.myfunc)
            t.start()
            t.join()
        myfunc(self.thn)

    def myfunc(num):
        print num,'\tI am doing sth.'
        sleep(0.5)
        print num,'\tI have done it.'

mythread()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to start the thread to make it actually do something:

```
t = mythread()
t.start()
```

If you bother to accept a `target` parameter in your constructor (why?), you shouldn't ignore this parameter.  Maybe you want to pass it on to the `Thread` constructor. (Why?)

Comment: I think I have start in the run() method. You are right! I found that spawn threads in run() method is kind of silly now. Thanks Marnach~

Comment: When you don't start the parent thread, it won't get a chance to launch the child threads.

Answer (score 1):

When you write `mythread()`, you instantiate the object. THe default constructor will be called, so `__init__()` will be executed.

You constructor doesn't have the any instruction of starting the thread.